# Is there an Angular 2 implementation of angular-better-placeholders?

Tags: angularjs, angular, input, placeholder

I liked angular-better-placeholders in AngularJS. There were a few implementations. Here's an example: https://github.com/dmackerman/angular-better-placeholders

I can't find something similar for Angular2. If there's not a plug-and-play implementation could someone provide some basic code snippets to get us started? I can't get any real scripting control over the text inside but I've got the following:

```
HTML:
<div class="input-container">
        <input id="test" class="col-xs-9 form-control" name="name" formControlName="name">
</div>

CSS:
.input-container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.input-container:after{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    content: 'Testing';
}
```

Which results in this:
[image]

Comment: its css based solution, why it needs angular 2?

Comment: Why you don't use ' [placeholder] = "myplaceholder"' it should be ok in angular2

Comment: I think `mdInput` from material2 looks close to what you are searching...
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/input/README.md